# Is passing class in java as argument good choice for getting information about concrete implementation of interface?

Tags: java, design-patterns

i have problem with interface's method. It's rather design problem than programming implementation problem.

I tried to implement Composite Design Pattern in my project. Firstly, I was using Enum to distinguish different kind of elements (getElementType was main method to ensure what information is inside the object - there were a lot of different Tree elements). This solution was terrible... I know

I deleted enum and created many smaller classes, used inheritance and implemented concrete method from my interface for each Object.

```
TreeElem elem; // ... etc

if(elem.getElementType()==ElemType.LEAF){
    elem.action();
}

public interface Actionable{
    void action();
}

public class ElemLeaf extends TreeElem implements Actionable{

    public void action(){
        // something funny haha
    }
}

Actionable elem = new ElemLeaf(); 

elem.action();
```

But sometimes I want to know, which class this object is, so I created method and added to Actionable interface

```
public Actionable doSomething(Class classOfElement){

    if(classOfElement.equals(ElemLeaf.class){

        return this;

    }
    else{

        return new ElemLeaf();

    }
}
```

I don't know if it is a good design principle to put Class as parameter or it is terrible choice. Maybe I should change my classes and interfaces composition to avoid this situation.

I hope that I made myself clear. These examples are not from my project, but they are similiar.

Comment: No, it's not a good design principle. Whenever you find yourself in a position where you "want to know the class of an object", you're *probably* doing something wrong designwise.

Comment: [The visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) might be what you are looking for.

Comment: @Kayman thx, instead of putting children of this element in list and trying to find the one as an object of correct class I just put fields with references to them, i don't have to find in a list now. Thx for answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just make `TreeElem` an `Actionable` which would delegate the `action` call to it's children. That way the caller doesn't have to care wheter it's children nodes are leafs or not.

If for some reason you have to handle concrete node types in many different ways when walking the tree then you may want to check the [Visitor Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

Comment: as I answered above instead of trying to find the correct children in a collection I put new fields with references, now i don't worry about the class of the child, it was only one case so I could afford to this.

Comment: In a Node i have list of children, in this specific element when I wanted to know the class of the child. There were always three elements, so instead using List<Node> I put new fields in this Node for each child
class SpecificNode{
private NodeA nodeA;
private NodeB nodeB;
private NodeC nodeC;
}

Comment: @gman1200 Oh ok, yeah that's a possibility. It might be more efficient this way, as long as children aren't dynamic. For instance an `IfNode` might have a `body` and a `condition` rather than a collection of 2 children elements.